# Do I need PS+ subscription for coop features?

Tags: death-stranding

There were some mentions before release about limited multiplayer features like seeing trails created by other players.

Do I need PS+ to see those?

[Store page](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA11260_00-DEATHSTRANDELUXE) says nothing about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, a PS+ subscription is not required for the multiplayer functions of Death Stranding. The integration of other player's structures, share locker items, etc. should integrate into your world, regardless of PS+ status.

Some sites are reporting that the lack of PS+ requirement is due to the lack of *direct* co-op play.

Sources:
https://kotaku.com/tips-for-playing-death-stranding-1839674810  (Build Stuff section)
https://www.tweaktown.com/news/67807/death-strandings-unique-multiplayer-require-ps-plus/index.html  (references a limited edition set sold at Game UK starting PS+ not required whose box says "Death Stranding does not require PlayStation Plus". For some reason, this sticker was not displayed on NA limited edition sets.)